# yii how to link to module images

Tags: yii

my Yii modules file structure looks like this

```
-yii
  -protected
     -modules
        -admin
           -controller
           -model
           -view
               -layout
                    -main.php
           -assets
               -css
                   -style.css
               -js
               -images
                   -logo.jpg
```

what i'm trying to do is access the **logo.jpg** from my `protected/views/site/index.php`. How do i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your should publish your assets first, then use this url. Add this code in your module:

```
class YourModule extends CWebModule
{
    private $_assetsUrl;

    public function getAssetsUrl()
    {
        if ($this->_assetsUrl === null)
            $this->_assetsUrl = Yii::app()->getAssetManager()->publish(__DIR__ . '/assets', false, -1, true);
        return $this->_assetsUrl;
    }
```

Then use this url:

```
$assets = $this->module->getAssetsUrl();
echo $assets . '/images/logo.jpg'
```

Comment: i'm getting an error here `<img class="media-object" src="<?php echo $assets . '/images/64x64.png'; ?>" alt="..." />`  it says `Undefined variable: assets `

Comment: $assets = $this->module->getAssetsUrl();

Comment: isn't `$this->module->getAssetsUrl();` used if you are calling from within the same module?

Comment: yes, to call from another module use Yii::app()->getModule('modulename')->getAssetsUrl()